# How to calculate the time complexity of this recursive function

Tags: algorithm, tree, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

I'm currently taking a course on algorithms and data structures, but I'm having some difficulty understanding how to calculate the complexity of this function as it involves a recursive function within another recursive function. Could someone provide some guidance, please?

Let x be the root of a Binary Search Tree (BST), and let's assume that the number of nodes is n.

**DISCLAIMER:** I am well aware that this function is highly inefficient. These functions have been written for illustrative purposes only.

Pseudocode:

```
countForEach(x){ //prints the number of nodes for each subtree of the tree rooted at x
    if(x != NIL){
        CountForEach(x.left)
        CountForEach(x.right)
        print(countRec(x))
    }
}

countRec(y) //returns the number of nodes in the subtree rooted in y
    if(y == NIL):
        return 0
    else:
        return countRec(y.left) + countRec(y.right) + 1
```

I know that `countRec(x)` has a time complexity of Θ(m), where m is the number of nodes in the subtree rooted at x and that `countRec(y)` is called by `countForEach(x)` n times where n is the number of nodes of the tree rooted at x.
What prevents me from reaching a solution is that m decreases as `CountForEach` executes.

Comment: Try computing it directly for a degenerate tree (each node except one has exactly 1 child) and for a complete tree.

Comment: For a degenerate tree, through the application of two summations I have obtained the result (n(n+1))/2, so in that case the time complexity is Θ(n^2). For the complete tree, on the other hand, I am unable to write the recurrence because of the call `countRec(x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments you've already derived what the result would be if the tree were *degenerate*, i.e. where each node only has one child, except for the (single) leaf node: +(−1)+...+3+2+1 = (+1)/2, which is θ(²). This is a worst case scenario in terms of .

A best case scenario occurs when the tree is perfect, i.e. where there is no node that has one child only and all leaves are at the same level.

Let ℎ be the height of the perfect binary tree; the number of nodes  is then equal to 2<sup>ℎ+1</sup>−1.

Counting the number of calls of `countRec` in a top-down manner, we get these terms per level of the tree:

2<sup>ℎ+1</sup>−1

+ 2<sup>1</sup>⋅(2<sup>ℎ</sup>−1)

+ 2<sup>2</sup>⋅(2<sup>ℎ−1</sup>−1)

+ 2<sup>3</sup>⋅(2<sup>ℎ−2</sup>−1)

+ ...

+ 2<sup>ℎ</sup>

Writing each term as the subtraction of two powers of 2:

= 2<sup>ℎ+1</sup>−2<sup>0</sup>

+ 2<sup>ℎ+1</sup>−2<sup>1</sup>

+ 2<sup>ℎ+1</sup>−2<sup>2</sup>

+ 2<sup>ℎ+1</sup>−2<sup>3</sup>

+ ...

+ 2<sup>ℎ+1</sup>−2<sup>ℎ</sup>

Adding up the terms:

= (ℎ+1)2<sup>ℎ+1</sup>−(2<sup>ℎ+1</sup>−1)

= ℎ2<sup>ℎ+1</sup>+1

As in this perfect tree =2<sup>ℎ+1</sup>−1, this translates to:

= (log<sub>2</sub>(+1)−1)(+1) + 1 which is θ(log)

In conclusion we can say the worst case time complexity is θ(²) and the best case time complexity is θ(log).

Answer (score 1):

Recursive algorithm for counting the number of nodes in each subtree of a binary tree. The function, `countForEach`, traverses the tree in a depth-first manner, visiting each node and printing the count of nodes in its subtree using the `countRec` function.

Let *n* be the total number of nodes in the binary tree:

1. `countForEach` function: In the worst case, it visits each node exactly once. Therefore, the time complexity for this function is **O(n)**.
2. `countRec` function: The time complexity of this function is also **O(n)** in the worst case, because it traverses each node exactly once.

Since both functions are called for each node in the tree, the overall time complexity of the provided code is **O(n * n)**, or **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**.

In summary, the time complexity of the code is quadratic in terms of the number of nodes in the binary tree.